# IIS Url Rewrite to Switch user back to HTTP

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have just installed URL rewrite module 2.0 on my server. I have following rules that switches the user from http to https if he is navigating to login or register view.

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to SSL for login and register" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^login.aspx$|^register.aspx$" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_Host}/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

This way when user tries to visit login or register pages on http, he is switched to relevant https page. But once user has logged in using https://server.com/login.aspx, I want him to navigate back to http. Precisely, I want to write a rule that all pages except login and register are forced on http. How would I do that? I think, I just need to figure out the regex of anything but register and login pages? What would that be like? I am not proficient with regex.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to SSL for login and register" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^login\.aspx$|^register\.aspx$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_Host}/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect to non-SSL for others" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^.*$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_Host}/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: OK you mean to say that rules are processed in order like url routing in mvc?

Comment: I think not. Adding these rules cause redirect loop problem at login.aspx and register.aspx. The reason is that when I try to go to `http://server/login.asxp`, it redirects to `https://server/login.aspx` and this time the second rule causes the redirect to http hence resulting in redirect loop.

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid - Parameter `stopProcessing="true"` prevents such loop

Comment: yes you are right but lets see how it happens. First request sent to `http://server/login.aspx` it matched the first rule and redirected to https counterpart. At this moment the processing is stopped but after redirection `https://server/login.aspx` is the second request. This time it does not match the first rule because of `https` condition. It however matches the second rule (url match matches everything and `https` is also on so it again redirects it to `http`address creating the loop. I figure, now i need the regex that does not matach `login.aspx` and `register.aspx`. does it make sense?

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid - I understand what you are saying. Try replace `<match url="^.*$" />` with `<match url="^(?!(?:login|register)\.aspx)$).*$" />`

Comment: Mismatched parenthesis. Do you mean `^(?!(?:login|register)\.aspx$).*$`? Please update the answer so I can mark it as answer.

Comment: This causes the js, css and image files to be redirected to http (even in an https page) causing insecure content warning :(